# vb.net find and replace inside wmf files

Tags: vb.net, metadata, wmf

I am struggling to open wmf files and run a simple ascii find and replace to look for certain characters in the metadata and replace with different values. any idea can this be done? I have a wmf editor that shows me the text inside the image is a proper windows font and not combination of lines and arcs. any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Check out this [Accessing WMF metadata with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14535/Accessing-WMF-metadata-with-C) article, porting it over should be pretty straight forward using code converters on the web.

Comment: thanks Raphael but I think the link is for windows media files i.e. audio and video filetypes. I am after windows metafile images (wmf pictures having drawings vector data) to read the images data blocks and run a search and replace and save the replaced values in the image.

Comment: No one has ever required to edit picture files like wmf(s)? NO help? Raphael, can you please tell me where I can download the wmfsdkwrapper. I don't have this sdk and can't test your suggested code either!

Comment: I think its part of the WMP11 SDK but this wasn't what you were looking for correct? (the digging i did also didn't come up with much so afraid i can't help you with this one.)